# Bochner integrability of $f$ and integrability of $|f|$: how are they related?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $f:X \to B$ be a Banach-valued map, where $X$ is a measure space. I am currently studying Bochner integration theory (that is, a theory for integrating Banach-valued functions).

In "Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitcherhiker's guide", the authors give the following theorem, without proof.

> If $X$ is a finite measure space and $f$ is measurable (that is, each Borel set has a measurable preimage), then $f$ is Bochner integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable in the usual sense.

In "Functional Analysis" by Kosaku Yosida, the following is given.

> If $f$ is strongly measurable (a.e. limit of measurable simple functions), $f$ is Bochner integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable in the usual sense.

I am quite confused because of the slightly different settings.
In the first theorem, $f$ is measurable while in the second theorem, $f$ is "strongly" measurable. (I think they may do not imply each other, especially when the underlying measure space $X$ is not complete).

Also, in the first theorem, $X$ is assumed to be a finite measure space, but in the second theorem, no such assumption is needed.

So here are my questions:

1. What is the precise relation between measurability and strong measurability?
2. Does the slogan "$f$ Bochner integrable iff $|f|$ integrable" holds for any measure space $X$? What technical conditions are needed?

Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://ocw.tudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/Lecture01_01.pdf) may help.

Comment: $B$ is a Banach space, and thus complete. In this case, I believe strongly measurable should imply measurable. (I say I believe since I think the proof for this for $\mathbb R$ should translate easily to a Banach space, but I'd want to think about it more carefully to be certain.) Presumably, the stronger hypothesis in Yosida is needed because Yosida does not assume a finite measure. Don't Aliprantis and Border give a reference for the first theorem?